# Django Query Filter by Date

Tags: python, django, filter, warnings

I am trying to query/filter a table for events that happened today eastern time, but I keep running into issues. It returns my expected result but I get a runtime warning. Iv't tried about 15 different implementations, but I either get a runtime warning or it doesn't return the expected data. While the database stores everything as utc as it should, the entire application is based solely on Eastern Time. All I want to do is filter objects that happened >= to 12:00 AM EST/EDT

RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime (2013-08-13 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.

The functionality I am after is to check how many entries a user has for today in Eastern time.

Using Sqlite3

```
Settings.py:
    USE_TZ = True
    TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'


Models.py

class Entry(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, null=False)
    prize_id = models.ForeignKey(Prize)
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member)
    createdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

Views.py
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime

    #this is part of my view class
    def get_user_entries(memberid, prizeid):
        today = datetime.date.today()
        e = Entry.objects.filter(member_id=memberid
        ).filter(prize_id=prizeid
        ).filter(createdate__gte=today
        ).count()
        return e
```

Here are some of the ways i tired to get todays date:

```
    today = datetime.date.today()
    today = '%s-%s-%s' % (today.year, today.month, today.day)

    date = datetime.date.today()
    time = datetime.time(00, 00, 00, 000000)
    combo = datetime.datetime.combine(date, time)

    hours = timezone.now().hour
    minutes = timezone.now().minute
    seconds = timezone.now().second
    mseconds = timezone.now().microsecond

    #convert timezone now to utc 04:00:00:000000 UTC
    # this works now and doesnt throw a runtime error and gives me the correct data im expecting, but i think it will be an hour off during dst
    t = timezone.now().replace(hour=04, minute=00, second=00, microsecond=000000)

    #I also tired this but still didnt get the expected results:
    e = Entry.objects.filter(member_id=1
        ).filter(prize_id=1
        ).filter(createdate__gte=timezone.now() -
        datetime.timedelta(hours=datetime.datetime.now().hour,
        minutes=datetime.datetime.now().minute,
        seconds=datetime.datetime.now().second,
        microseconds=datetime.datetime.now().microsecond))
```

Does any one have an easy way to get objects with a time stamp >= to today?

Comment: try to use the `django.utils.timezone` module to create a datetime instead of the `datetime` module.

Answer (score 1):

Just come up with something else:

by doing a queryset:

```
today= todaydate (use timezone to get it)
today_entry = Entry.objects.filter(date1=today).count()
```

can you try?

count_reward = Rewards.objects.filter(user=request.user).filter(routine=d).count()

Did you import from your models  Entry?

```
from models import Entry
```

If you want to get all the object created after 12AM. ( I suppose all elements created or modified today?)

my models.py

```
class Mecdatebis(models.Model):
    text1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date1 = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.text1
```

i create a model that have a CharField (to recognize if the entry appears in my html for the good one)
a DateTimeField(auto_now=True) that create the Timestamp you are looking for.

in my views.py:

```
from models import Mecdatebis
from datetime import *

def date(request):
    now = datetime.now()
    test = Mecdatebis.objects.all()   #get all the data from your models
    return render_to_response('date.html', {
        'mydate': test,
        'now' : now }
        )
```

the "mydate" is all the field that Mecdatebis have (text1 and date1)
the now is equal to the date on your system

then on my template:

```
{% for mesdate in mydate %}

    {% if now.year == mesdate.date1.year and now.month == mesdate.date1.month and now.day == mesdate.date1.day %}
        {{mesdate.text1}}       
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

My test is as follow:
If the time that I have now on my system is == at the year of my timestamp
and if the month of my date now is == of the month of my timestamp 
and if the day (the number) of my date now is == of the timestamp day. Then show me all the entry of the same date.

So at least we get the object.
but counting them I had difficulty.
I tried to apply the same method in the views. without success
I hope someone can come here and get something working.